# Windows 2008 SBS Remote Applications

Tags: windows-server-2008

We are looking at upgrading our network infrastructure, primarily moving our Sage accounting package to a dedicated server.

The plan is to allow remote users VPN access to the network so that they can work on the Sage.

The server will be running Windows Server 2008 SBE.

I understand that Windows Server 2008 will only allow three simultaneous remote sessions and to enable more we need to install Remote Desktop Services (Terminal Service). Does this need to be on a different server or can it be installed on the same server as our Sage software.

Any recommended resources or tutorials on setting up remote access applications.

Many thanks for all the Help.

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop Services (formerly Terminal Services) must be installed on the machine you intend to host the application that the users will use.  In other words, if you plan to run Sage on a dedicated box then you should also host RDS there as well.

My best suggestion for you though is to go find a book or administrators guide on Remote Desktop Services to guide you through the process.  Depending on your company you may also want to bring in a consultant or company to help you set up RDS, it can be a bit of a pain if you're not familiar with it, especially the licensing aspect.